# Динамическое изменение значения переменной и вывод в label WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, binding

У меня имеется страница с 4 текстбоксами и целочисленная переменная SkillsRemains для отображения очков, которая изначально равна 8. К каждому событию создал событие TextChanged для изменения значения этой переменной, чтобы от нее отнималось то значение, что я непосредственно прописываю в текстбоксе. При этом мне хочется, чтобы на страницу в label при помощи привязки выводилось значение изменяемой переменной, чтобы было видно, сколько очков осталось. Искал информацию и пробовал что-то сделать с PropertyChanged, но не получилось

```
private void CMDSkills_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SkillsRemains -= int.Parse(CMDSkills.Text);            
}

private void GUISkills_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SkillsRemains -= int.Parse(GUISkills.Text);
}

private void LanguageSkills_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SkillsRemains -= int.Parse(LanguageSkills.Text);
}

private void AlgorithmsSkills_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SkillsRemains -= int.Parse(AlgorithmsSkills.Text);
}
```

Это часть xaml кода

```
<Label Content="{Binding SkillsRemains}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0, -15, 80, 0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Прочитайте про основы привязок, хотяб тут, на SO пару ответов на эту тему посмотрите, даже можете от меня, тогда вы поймете, что вам не нужно вовсе событие изменения на каждый контрол, а еще вы поймете, что нужен INotifyPropertyChanged для обновления UI.

Comment: `Label` - наследие Winforms. Если вам нужно показать текст в интерфейсе, используйте вместо него `TextBlock`, он как минимум кушает меньше памяти и быстрее работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Просмотрел два вопроса на тему привязки, но не до конца понял, как я могу в своем случае избавиться от событий для каждого из контролов, описанных выше, чтобы менять значение одной своей переменной. Видимо, я невнимателен...

Comment: Ну как так, я прямым текстом сказал, что надо реализовать INPC, чтоб он обновил данные в UI. Так что да, невнимательны. Зайдите в мой профиль и сверху в поиске допишите `INotifyPropertyChanged` и найдете много ответов с подробным описанием. А по поводу `избавиться от событий` - а зачем вам они? Делаете свойство, допустим `private langSkills; public int LanguageSkillls { get => langSkills; set { langSkills = value; SkillsRemains -= value; OnPropertyChanged();  } }` и радуетесь, заметьте, что свойство с типом `int` (постоянная конвертация не нужна) и в `set` задана логика.

Comment: Либо можете вовсе пойти через тот же INPC, подписаться на `PropertyChanged` событие и следить за тем, какое свойство было изменено и уже отталкиваться через это. Так что, как видите, привязки решают полностью вашу задачу и даже нет необходимости писать `LanguageSkills.Text` и как либо иначе обращаться к UI. Почитайте про привязки, про MVVM можете почитать, посмотрите как грамотно разрабатыается WPF проект, а то у вас каша, где вы вроде и используете некое подобие привязок, а вроде и обращаетесь к UI через код, а это, плохо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как до меня сразу не дошло так сделать... Огромное спасибо за идею! Извините за, возможно, глупый вопрос, но нужно ли описывать поле SkillsRemains для вывода в условно тот же Label или textBlock?

Comment: Свойство, работайте с ними, ибо привязки в WPF разрешены только к публичным свойствам. Имея такое свойство с логикой и даже с `int` типом, вы без труда сможете его привязать куда вам угодно (`<TextBlock Text="{Binding SkillsRemains}" />`).